# Itemize with tags

Tags: lists

Is there an itemize or enumerate like environment that allows you to use words preceding each item instead of a dot or number. So it'll output something nice for text structures like the following:

**Blogiddy Bloop** --- A bloggidy bloop is a thing that does stuff.

**Apwitchik** --- A apwitchik is a thing that does other stuff.

**Deddydoo** --- A Deddydoo does all the stuff a Bloggiddy Bloop and an Apwitchik do, but even more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A regular `description` environment does this for you. It typesets its argument in **bold**, although this can be modified using the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[Blogiddy Bloop] --- A bloggidy bloop is a thing that does stuff.
  \item[Apwitchik] --- A apwitchik is a thing that does other stuff.
  \item[Deddydoo] --- A Deddydoo does all the stuff a Bloggiddy Bloop and an Apwitchik do, but even more.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

If you want to add the `---` style, you could create a command (say) `\descitem[<item>]` to include this by default. `<item>` is optional, and defaults to `Item`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\descitem}[1][Item]{\item[#1~---]}%
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \descitem[Blogiddy Bloop] A bloggidy bloop is a thing that does stuff.
  \descitem[Apwitchik] A apwitchik is a thing that does other stuff.
  \descitem[Deddydoo] A Deddydoo does all the stuff a Bloggiddy Bloop and an Apwitchik do, but even more.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `{description}` environment.  Use like this:

```
\begin{description}
 \item[label 1] First item.
 \item[label 2] Second item.
\end{description}
```

The labels will be whatever you put in the square brackets.